# How to increase speed of a data entry application used by multiple users?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

We are four in a team using a data entry application created using VB and MS Access as backend DB. The application is installed on all our PCs, but uses my PC as server. We enter data at same time. The application has been slow since we started using it. We were advised to increase the internet bandwidth, which we doubled, but the application is still slow. What can be done to increase the speed of the application to make work move faster?

Comment: Your caps lock key seems to be broken - can you fix it before asking a question?

Comment: tL;dr - too LOUD, didn't read.

Comment: Apparently you need a new keyboard, your shift key is stuck.

Comment: OP: You're welcome...don't do that again!

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you won't get many answers, mostly because your post is so vague. I highly doubt that your being restricted by your "internet bandwidth", especially because it sounds like you're all on the same network. If it's going slowly, I would probably blame poor programming or underpowered hardware, however nobody on this site will be able to give you a definitive answer because there's not nearly enough information. Get somebody local that can take a look at it - somebody other than the person who told you to double your bandwidth...